# Extract all characters after a sequence using regexp in java/android

Tags: java, regex

Imagine these String:

```
String s = "firstpartie_FOO_lastpartieofthestring"
```

or

```
String s = "lllalal_FOOBBARR_lastpartieofthestringofthedead"
```

With regexp, i want to extract the string after the second "_".

I've tried this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=_[A-Z]*_)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("lllalal_FOOBBARR_lastpartieofthestringofthedead")
```

But how to finish the regexp to extract the string  "lastpartieofthestringofthedead" ?

Comment: Just split it using `_` and take 3rd array element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this way:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_[A-Z]*_(.*)");
```

I progress in regex study hi hi hi ;-)

Explained:

...after an underscore followed by any number (use of star) of uppercase chars =>    [A-Z]*, followed by another underscore  =>    _[A-Z]*_

... , capture all characters =>   (.*)

Find example here: https://ideone.com/S5WJMr

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fix your approach, capture the rest of the string with a capturing group:

```
String s = "lllalal_FOOBBARR_lastpartieofthestringofthedead";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^_]*_[^_]*_(.*)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
// => lastpartieofthestringofthedead
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/rIR9CN)

Here, `^[^_]*_[^_]*_(.*)` matches the start of string (`^`), 0+  chars other than `_` (`[^_]*`), `_`, again 0+  chars other than `_` and a `_`, and then captures the rest of the string into Group 1 (with `(.*)`).

Else, split into 3 parts with `_`:

```
String s = "lllalal_FOOBBARR_lastpartieofthestring_of_thedead";
String[] res = s.split("_", 3);
if (res.length > 2) {
    System.out.println(res[2]);
} 
// => lastpartieofthestring_of_thedead
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/JJMQTE)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it looks for any amount of characters followed by a `_` then another amount of characters followed by `_` and captures everything else:

`.*_.*_(.*)`

And an example on Regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/sfVyL2/1